# Tic Tac Toe Loop/Method running too many times

Tags: java, loops, methods, execution, tic-tac-toe

UPDATE: I found that the problem is in the Mouse() method. It will run and take values until you let go of the mouse. I need a way to pause the program or stop it until someone releases the mouse.

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe game and I think I got it to only one problem left. I got it to work perfect, but then I messed with it to try and make the messages appear on the actual game instead of just the java interaction pane(excuse me if these aren't the right terms to use)
For some reason when I run, it will take the first move correctly and then it acts as if someone keeps clicking on the same place on the board and gives me an invalid input error multiple times. I'm not sure what to do to fix this problem, but I'm guessing the error is in the Fill() method. Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
 /* 
 * Tic Tac Toe Game
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game {
    //Create Variables
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static double a;
    public static double b;
    public static int empty = 0;
    public static int Cross = 1;
    public static int Oh = -1;
    public static double[][] board = new double[3][3];
    public static int currentPlayer;
    public static int p = 1;
    //public static boolean v = false;


    //Main method: draws the board and then begins game
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        initalize();
        drawBoard();
        // System.out.println("X's turn.");
        for(int w = 0; w < 9; w++) {
            turn();
            Fill();
        }
    }


    /* 
     * this method creates the graphic as a 9x9 board with the 'hashtag' for playing
     */
    public static void drawBoard() {
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, 9);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 9);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(.01);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
        StdDraw.line(0, 3, 9, 3);
        StdDraw.line(0, 6, 9, 6);
        StdDraw.line(3, 0, 3, 9);
        StdDraw.line(6, 0, 6, 9);
    } //end draw board

    public static void initalize() {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
                board[j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * this method will take the coordinates of the mouse when clicked as a,b coordinates
     * the it will take the a,b coordinates and turn them into an x,y board position (0-2)
     */
    public static void Mouse() {
        while(true) {
            if(StdDraw.mousePressed()) {
                a = StdDraw.mouseX();
                b = StdDraw.mouseY();
                //System.out.println( a + " " + b);
                //board location
                //set column
                if(0 <= a && a < 3) {
                    x = 0;
                }
                if(3 <= a && a < 6) {
                    x = 1;
                }
                if(6 <= a && a < 9) {
                    x = 2;
                }
                //set row
                if(0 <= b && b < 3) {
                    y = 0;
                }
                if(3 <= b && b < 6) {
                    y = 1;
                }
                if(6 <= b && b < 9) {
                    y = 2;
                }
                //System.out.println("You clicked in Row" + x + "and column" +y);
                break;
            }
        }
    }//ends Mouse


    /*
     * Runs CurrentPlayer() to deicde who the current player is and then prints a message with whose turn it is
     */
    public static void turn() {
        CurrentPlayer();
        if(currentPlayer != Cross) {
            System.out.println("O's turn.");
        }
        if(currentPlayer != Oh) {
            System.out.println("X's turn.");
        }
    }

    /*
     * this method determines if it is player X or player O
     * it flip flops each time it is called and reurns the value of the 'currentPlayer' (-1 or 1)
     */
    public static int CurrentPlayer() {
        if(p % 2 == 0) {
            currentPlayer = Oh;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = Cross;
        }
        return currentPlayer;
    }//ends CurrentPlayer


    /*
     * this method is the actual 'playing'
     * it calls Mouse() to get coordinates/board location
     * determines if it is a valid move by making sure its within the board range and also checking to make sure that array spot of the board it empty(0) 
     * it then fills the array with the value of the currentplayer, prints the board, checks the game status for a win, adds a turn, and restarts if it is valid.
     * if its not vaild it will tell you and then restart to get a valid move
     */
    public static void Fill() {
        Mouse();
        //check if valid
        if(0 <= x && x <= 2 && 0 <= y && y <= 2 && board[x][y] == 0) {
            //switch player
            p++;
            //fill array spot
            board[x][y] = currentPlayer;
            //check game status and print board
            PrintBoard();
            GameStatus();
            return;//exit method
        }
        //move is not valid
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid. Try again.");
            Fill();
        }
    }//ends Fill()

    /*
     *scrolls through board array to check for moves.
     * if array value=0, its empty and does nothing
     * if array value=1, its X and prints an X in that board position
     * if array value=-1, its O and prints an O in that board position
     */
    public static void PrintBoard() {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
                if(board[j][k] == 0) {
                    //do nothing leave empty
                }
                Font mark = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60);

                if(board[j][k] == 1) {
                    double l = ((j + 1) * 3) - 1.5;
                    double m = ((k + 1) * 3) - 1.5;
                    //print x
                    StdDraw.setFont(mark);
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
                    StdDraw.text(l, m, "X");
                }
                if(board[j][k] == -1) {
                    double l = ((j + 1) * 3) - 1.5;
                    double m = ((k + 1) * 3) - 1.5;
                    //print O
                    StdDraw.setFont(mark);
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
                    StdDraw.text(l, m, "O");
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }//Ends PrintBoard()

    /*
     * this method checks if there is a win, cats game, or if the game is still in play
     * if its a win it determines if it is an X win or O win and prints out a winners message coorespondingnto who won
     * if its a cats game, it prints out cats game
     * it the game is still in play it says keep playing and goes back to the Fill() method
     */
    public static void GameStatus() {
        Font win = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100);
        Font cat = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 80);

        //check for win
        if(// First column
                board[0][0] == currentPlayer && board[0][1] == currentPlayer && board[0][2] == currentPlayer
                        //second column
                        || board[1][0] == currentPlayer && board[1][1] == currentPlayer && board[1][2] == currentPlayer
                        //third column
                        || board[2][0] == currentPlayer && board[2][1] == currentPlayer && board[2][2] == currentPlayer
                        //first row
                        || board[0][0] == currentPlayer && board[1][0] == currentPlayer && board[2][0] == currentPlayer
                        //second row
                        || board[0][1] == currentPlayer && board[1][1] == currentPlayer && board[2][1] == currentPlayer
                        //third row
                        || board[0][2] == currentPlayer && board[1][2] == currentPlayer && board[2][2] == currentPlayer
                        //diagonal 1
                        || board[0][2] == currentPlayer && board[1][1] == currentPlayer && board[2][0] == currentPlayer
                        // diagonal 2
                        || board[2][2] == currentPlayer && board[1][1] == currentPlayer && board[0][0] == currentPlayer) {
            //X win
            while(currentPlayer == 1) {
                StdDraw.setFont(win);
                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
                StdDraw.text(4.5, 4.5, "X Won!");
            }
            //O win
            while(currentPlayer == -1) {
                StdDraw.setFont(win);
                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
                StdDraw.text(4.5, 4.5, "O Won!");
            }
            return;
        }

        //cats game
        else if(board[0][0] != 0 && board[0][1] != 0 && board[0][2] != 0 && board[1][0] != 0 && board[1][1] != 0 && board[1][2] != 0 && board[2][0] != 0 && board[2][1] != 0 && board[2][2] != 0) {
            StdDraw.setFont(cat);
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.YELLOW);
            StdDraw.text(4.5, 4.5, "Cat's Game!");
            return;
        }

        //still playing
        else {
            System.out.println("Keep Playing.");
            return;
        }
    }//Ends GameStatus
}// End Class Game
```

Comment: "`while (currentPlayer==1){`" What do you think causes this condition to become false?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: @AndyTurner if you look at the variables on top, if the currentPlayer is Cross it will be 1 and if currentPlayer is Oh, it will be -1.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I have no idea how to do that nor have I heard of that as I'm relatively new to programming and our teacher hasn't talked about that.

Comment: @GabbieGrapes yes, but how does that condition become false once you are inside that loop? Unless you've got multiple threads, nothing will change the variable, so the condition never changes.

Comment: @AndyTurner   It will only go to that loop once it passes the if statement which means that you won so you wouldn't need to break out of that loop anyways. 
I found out that the problem is in the Mouse() method because if I hold my mouse down that's how many invalid messages I get. So I need a way to pause it or wait for the mouse to be release.